# CSS Grid content-area horizontally expansion for filling the container

Tags: css, css-grid, css-transforms, expand

I have a CSS Grid container and a sidebar and content area inside it. I want to when user close the sidebar, content area, horizontally expands to fill the whole width of the container.
I've used transformX(-100%) on hover the sidebar for hiding and transformX(0%) for showing the sidebar on mouse out in my bellow sample:

```css
.test-container {
  display: grid;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar content";
  height: 100vh;
}

.test-sidebar {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 2000ms;
}

.test-sidebar:hover {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: 2000ms;
}

.test-content {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: content;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-container">
  <div class="test-sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="test-content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we use Js for this?

Comment: I prefer to use a css-only solution if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with hovering on all grid element, just to demonstrate, how we can act with two different cells. Here we have `grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;` in `.test-container` and static width in `.test-sidebar`. Now they are expanding/collapsing like you want.

About other behave, what does it mean "when user close the sidebar"? Describe this action pleas. Describe both behave of the sidebar, in which case it should collapse and expand? I think, the whole solution will requires JS. I will add it after your description, if needed.

```css
.test-container {
  display: grid;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.test-sidebar {
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.test-container:hover .test-sidebar {
  width: 0;
}

.test-content {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-container">
  <div class="test-sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="test-content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this is an amazing solution except animation for sliding in and out, the sidebar.

Comment: You can regulate animation by changing `transition: all 2s ease;` in `.test-container` and `.test-sidebar`. If I can somehow improve this code - just tell me about desired result.

Comment: If I remove width for sidebar from your style and add  margin-left: -200px; inside the .test-container:hover .test-sidebar section the animation will become like what I want but I think using negative margin technically is not a good idea.

Comment: Negative margin is absolutely OK, it uses in many solutions. In Bootstrap 4 grid  you can see negative margin in every `.row`

Comment: Thanks. So I will use negative margin.

Comment: And for closing the sidebar I use JavaScript. Here I just used hover for simplifying my example.